# Here's the code for a simple page I have that is not working:

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a booking application. I have written the following code. But I am not able to hide the fields. I want to display the specific form options depending upon the radio button selected. Please suggest... (I am not an expert in PHP)

```
<?php
session_start();
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$search = $_REQUEST['search'];


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("input[type=radio]").on('click', function(){
    if(this.id == 'radio1')
        $("#grid_1.omega").slideDown("slow");
    else
       $("#grid_1.omega").slideUp("slow");
});

});
</script>



<title>Car Booking system</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    color: #0000CC;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.omega{
    display: none;
}


-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="552" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><span class="style1">Book A Car Online</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <label>
        <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radio1" />
        Pick-up Only</label>
      <label>
      <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radio2" />
      Pick-up and Drop</label>
      <label>
      <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radio3" />
      Hourly Package</label>
      <label>
      <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radio4" />
      Packages</label>
    </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <div id="grid_1" class="omega" style="display:none">
    <td width="2">&nbsp;</td>

    <td width="152">Pickup City : </td>
    <td width="300"><select name="type" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:180px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Pickup Location : </td>
    <td><select name="select" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:180px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Pickup Date : </td>
    <td><input name="search" type="text" id="demo1" size="25"/>
      <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('demo1')"> <img src="Images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Pickup Time : </td>
    <td><select name="select5" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:50px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select> <select name="select6" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:50px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>
    </div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Return City : </td>
    <td><select name="select2" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:180px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Return Location : </td>
    <td><select name="select3" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:180px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Return Date : </td>
    <td><input name="search2" type="text" id="demo2" size="25"/>
      <a href="javascript:NewCssCal('demo2')"> <img src="Images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Pick a date" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Return Time : </td>
    <td><select name="select7" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:50px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select>
      <select name="select7" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:50px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
        <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
        <option value ="0">Select</option>
        <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Car Category : </td>
    <td><select name="select4" onchange='javascript: showStates(this.value)'  style="width:180px;background:#3399CC; border:thin; color:#FFFFFF"  >
      <?php
            $mdq7=$td->type;
            $qq7="SELECT * FROM type WHERE type_id='$mdq7'";
            $rrs7=mysql_query($qq7);
            $rqa7=mysql_fetch_object($rrs7);
            ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rqa7->type_id   ?>" ><?php echo $rqa7->type_name   ?></option>
      <option value ="0">Select</option>
      <?php
        $sel8 = "SELECT * FROM type";
        $res8 = mysql_query($sel8);
        while($rec8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res8))
        {
    echo "<option value=$rec8[type_id]>$rec8[type_name]</option>";
        }
          ?>
    </select></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to make a booking system application. I want the end user to see specific Form options depending upon the radio button that user select's, and all the remaining form options must be hidden.. 
    
    I have written this code but this is not hiding the form options..
    
    Please suggest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(this.id == 'radio1')
```

None of your `input[type=radio]` elements have `id` attributes.  They have `value` attributes, and that's what you need to be getting.

```
if(this.value == 'radio1')
```

Or with jQuery

```
if($(this).val() == 'radio1')
```

Comment: Tried the changes, still it's not working :

Comment: What *exactly* isn't working?  Do you see errors?  What *does* happen vs. what you want to happen?

Comment: I want the only pickup related options displayed when the first radio button is selected. and so on..
But not it's displaying all the fields by default

Comment: I am sorry.. No errors displayed but just all the fields r displaying